# Whole Page Clickable, Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, cursor

I have this piece of code in my style sheet to change the cursor to a pointer on one page, and it works well except on firefox, where it doesn't give you a "pointer" finger to let you know the page is clickable.

```
   html { 
    cursor:pointer;
    }
```

The thing is, the normal method of putting an onclick event in the body tag isn't working. (shown below not working)

```
<body onclick="window.href.location=filename">
body text
</body>
```

How do I get a pointer finger on the whole page instead of the normal mouse cursor in firefox?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? Give us some insight...your goal, etc.

Comment: the whole page is clickable, but without a pointer or saying something on the page, people won't know lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to fill your whole screen with the element.

```
html { 
  cursor:pointer;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

[Check this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/leonardorb/BK52j/2/) that I put together for you.

Comment: actually it is mike. i already had cursor:pointer in my original as seen at the top of the page. and thank you @leonardo now it works great.

Answer (score 3):

Add a hover rule to the body element.

```
body:hover {
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to fill the entire page with some element like:

```
<div style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px">
</div>
```

and use this inside the body. There you probaly need to care about the bodies margins.

Or you append a click handler to the entire window via JavaScrip:

```
window.addEventListener("click", doSomething, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make life easy:

```
<a href="#" id="page" onclick="JScode()"></a>
```

CSS

```
#page{display:block;position:absolute;top:0;bottom:0:left:0;right:0;}
```